# Cannot find resource that is defined in ControlTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml, resources

I have a resource dictionary with a style for my window. In this style i define the template and inthere i define a lot of stuff. Among others i define a storyboard to animate certain things that are defined in the template. It look something like this:

```
<Style TargetType="local:MyWindow">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="red" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:MyWindow">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.Resources>
                        <Storyboard x:Key="MyAnimation">
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ToBeAnimated" ... />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </Grid.Resources>
                    <Grid x:Name="ToBeAnimated" Background="Green"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Now i have an instance of MyWindow (which definitly applys the style :) ) and from within the window i want to trigger the animation. However, this

```
this.FindResource("MyAnimation");
```

fails!

If i move the storyboard in the

```
<ControlTemplate.Resources/>
```

it can find it, but if i do

```
((Storyboard)FindResource("StoryboardOpenOverlay")).Begin();
```

i get another error that it cannot find the `ToBeAnimated`...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a name on the Grid and use templated part to get a reference on it, to do that:
-Add `[TemplatePart(Name = "gridName",DataGrid.headerName, Type = typeof(Grid))]` on you MyWindow class
-And implement OnApplyTemplate:

```
    protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        Grid grid = this.GetTemplateChild("gridName") as Grid;
        if (grid != null)
        {
            Storyboard storyboard = grid.Resources["MyAnimation"] as Storyboard ;

        }
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
    }
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. Actually i can call this.GetTemplateChild(...) whenever i want, not only in the OnApplyTemplate(). Thanks!

Comment: I prefer to do it in ApplyTemplate and save the value in a local field, like this you save the cost of calling GetTemplateChild each time

Answer (score 1):

Though the storyboard is placed in your `Grid`, try this:

```
((Grid)this.Content).FindResource("MyAnimation");
```

or, if it is possible,

```
this.ToBeAnimated.FindResource("MyAnimation");
```

Comment: don't think that work, this.Content will be whatever is in the ContentTemplate not ControlTemplate and you cannot this.ToBeAnimated use because it's defined in a style

Comment: this.Content is the Grid and because the Storyboard is located there, it should work.

Comment: No this.Content might be a Grid but not the grid inside the ControlTemplate, it will be whatever is inside the ContentTemplate. (If it is defined the content is shown inside the ContentPresenter not directly at the ControlTemplate level)

Comment: Like the current style is defined, there is no ContentPresenter so the Content will not even be shown (or MyWindows might not even be a ContentControl...)