# Windows Phone 8 - Two-State ImageButton Template

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Right now I'm trying to figure out how to create a template for an `ImageButton` with two states (pressed and normal) and an `Image` for each state.

1. state normal: show image "buttonname.png", hide "buttonname_pressed.png"
2. state pressed: hide image "buttonname.png", show "buttonname_pressed.png"

So I created a new `Style` in the `Application.Resources`.

**Application.Resources:**

```xml
<Style x:Key="ImageButton" TargetType="Button">

    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid Background="Transparent" Height="90">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="imageNormal">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="imagePressed">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="imageNormal">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="imagePressed">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                    <Image x:Name="imageNormal"  Source="{Binding ???}"  Stretch="UniformToFill" />
                    <Image x:Name="imagePressed" Source="{Binding ???}" Stretch="UniformToFill" />

                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Now I want to create 3 different `ImageButton`s with different images, and this is what I don't understand. (° へ °)

I tried to use `Binding` and an `AttachedProperty`...

**Binding of the Image Source:**

```xml
Source="{Binding SourceNormal, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
```

**AttachedProperty:**

```cs
namespace HTML5App1.Resources.AttachedProperty
{
    public static class ImageButton
    {
        /////////////////////// SourceNormal /////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        public static readonly DependencyProperty SourceNormal = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "SourceNormal",
            typeof(string),
            typeof(ImageButton),
            new PropertyMetadata(null)
        );

        public static string GetSourceNormal(UIElement element)
        {
            if (element == null)
            {
                new ArgumentNullException("element");
            }
            return (string)element.GetValue(SourceNormal);
        }

        public static void SetSourceNormal(UIElement element, string value)
        {
            if (element == null)
            {
                new ArgumentNullException("element");
            }

            element.SetValue(SourceNormal, value);
        }
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        /////////////////////// SourcePressed ////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        public static readonly DependencyProperty SourcePressed = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "SourcePressed",
            typeof(string),
            typeof(ImageButton),
            new PropertyMetadata(null)
        );

        public static string GetSourcePressed(UIElement element)
        {
            if (element == null)
            {
                new ArgumentNullException("element");
            }
            return (string)element.GetValue(SourcePressed);
        }

        public static void SetSourcePressed(UIElement element, string value)
        {
            if (element == null)
            {
                new ArgumentNullException("element");
            }

            element.SetValue(SourcePressed, value);
        }
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    }
}
```

**MainPage.xaml:**

```xml
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HTML5App1.Resources.AttachedProperty"

<Button
    Style="{StaticResource ImageButton}"
    local:ImageButton.SourceNormal="/Assets/Images/button.png"
    local:ImageButton.SourcePressed="/Assets/Images/button_pressed.png"
    Grid.Column="1"
    Click="Button_Clicked"
    />
```

If I build the application I get an error message for both bindings:

```xml
An exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
System.Windows.Data Error: BindingExpression path error: 'SourceNormal' property not found on 'System.Windows.Controls.Button' 'System.Windows.Controls.Button' (HashCode=45028263). BindingExpression: Path='SourceNormal' DataItem='System.Windows.Controls.Button' (HashCode=45028263); target element is 'System.Windows.Controls.Image' (Name='imageNormal'); target property is 'Source' (type 'System.Windows.Media.ImageSource')..
System.Windows.Data Error: BindingExpression path error: 'SourcePressed' property not found on 'System.Windows.Controls.Button' 'System.Windows.Controls.Button' (HashCode=45028263). BindingExpression: Path='SourcePressed' DataItem='System.Windows.Controls.Button' (HashCode=45028263); target element is 'System.Windows.Controls.Image' (Name='imagePressed'); target property is 'Source' (type 'System.Windows.Media.ImageSource')..
```

But i can't figure out what I am doing wrong - can someone point me in the right direction?

**Other Questions:**

- is there an "easier" way to create a ImageButton Template from Button - can i access the `Normal` and the `Pressed` VisualState of the Button or listen to it and change the Image.Source if it is Normal or Pressed?
- is there an "easier" way to access the `Image.Source` in the `Grid` in the `Button`, without using `Binding`s (either in XAML or in C#)?
- is there a good tutorial for Bindings and Templates in XAML, I am somewhat of a beginner in XAML

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Why not just edit the Template of a `ToggleButton` to suit your purpose instead? Then you have all your states and you can just plop your images in it.

Comment: @ChrisW. I don't think ToggleButton is right there, toggle button would be if when you click it show one image, then you click again it show the other one (not a press and not press state)

Comment: @ChrisW. thank you for the hint, but as Benoit Catherinet stated I need different pressed states (normal, pressed) and I might want to add an image for the disabled state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
<Image x:Name="imageNormal"  Source="{TemplateBinding local:ImageButton.SourcePressed}"  Stretch="UniformToFill" />
```

Also instead of using string for the type of the two attached property you should use ImageSource.

In response to you other question it could be possible for you to do it in code by creating a custom control inheriting button and then you could access all the element inside the style by name using what is call TemplatedPart. See example [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18785671/cannot-find-resource-that-is-defined-in-controltemplate) (it's WPF but it work exactly the same for wp). But anyway I think the way  you are currently fdoing it is the right way.

Regarding article:
this [msdn documention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/cc278072%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) provide a good start with some example but don't talk of the more advance binding senario

Edit here is the full code that I tested and work for me:

The dependency property (switch string to ImageSource and use a different name for the dep property and the actual property):

```
public static class ImageButton
{



    /////////////////////// SourceNormal /////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SourceNormalProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "SourceNormal",
        typeof(ImageSource),
        typeof(ImageButton),
        new PropertyMetadata(null)
    );

    public static ImageSource GetSourceNormal(UIElement element)
    {
        if (element == null)
        {
            new ArgumentNullException("element");
        }
        return (ImageSource)element.GetValue(SourceNormalProperty);
    }

    public static void SetSourceNormal(UIElement element, ImageSource value)
    {
        if (element == null)
        {
            new ArgumentNullException("element");
        }

        element.SetValue(SourceNormalProperty, value);
    }
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /////////////////////// SourcePressed ////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SourcePressedProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "SourcePressed",
        typeof(ImageSource),
        typeof(ImageButton),
        new PropertyMetadata(null)
    );

    public static ImageSource GetSourcePressed(UIElement element)
    {
        if (element == null)
        {
            new ArgumentNullException("element");
        }
        return (ImageSource)element.GetValue(SourcePressedProperty);
    }

    public static void SetSourcePressed(UIElement element, ImageSource value)
    {
        if (element == null)
        {
            new ArgumentNullException("element");
        }

        element.SetValue(SourcePressedProperty, value);
    }
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
}
```

The style (just use TemplateBinding as explain above):

```
<Style x:Key="ImageButton" TargetType="Button">

        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>

        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent" Height="90">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="imageNormal">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="imagePressed">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="imageNormal">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="imagePressed">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                        <Image x:Name="imageNormal"  Source="{TemplateBinding local:ImageButton.SourceNormal}"  Stretch="UniformToFill" />
                        <Image x:Name="imagePressed" Source="{TemplateBinding local:ImageButton.SourcePressed}" Stretch="UniformToFill" />

                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

The button (no change):

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource ImageButton  }" 
                local:ImageButton.SourceNormal="/Assets/ApplicationIcon.png"
                local:ImageButton.SourcePressed="/Assets/Tiles/FlipCycleTileLarge.png"/>
```

Comment: The only thing I get is an Error:

    `The property "SourceNormal" is not a DependencyProperty. To be used in markup, non-attached properties must be exposed on the target type with an accessible instance property "SourceNormal". For attached properties, the declaring type must provide static "GetSourceNormal"  and "SetSourceNormal" methods. ...\HTML5App1\App.xaml`

Comment: If i change the type of `SourcePressed` or `SourceNormal` from `string` to `ImageSource` the App dosen't compile (and with `string` the Button dosen't show either).

Comment: Updated my response with the full source code of what I tested and work for me

Comment: thank you very much, I actually forgot to set the return type of the get-methods in the ImageButton from `string` to `ImageSource` - argh. I still get some strange error: `ImageButton is not supported in a Silverlight project. ...\HTML5App1\App.xaml` but it dosen't seem to affect the building of the application (there is also an somewhat unrelated error since I added the ImageButton style `The namespace prefix "local" is not defined.` for `<local:LocalizedStrings xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HTML5App1" x:Key="LocalizedStrings"/>`). Thanks alot for your help ;)

Comment: These error are just error from the designer, if you close and reopen the xaml file, they will probably go away.

Comment: Do you know how I create an `AttachedProperty` for the alignments (horizontal & vertical) and also for the size (height & width) - is there some documentation for this kind of stuff?

I want to resize the image inside of my ImageButton and also change the alignment.

Comment: You could just the "standard" property for that. For the size, just use the Padding as the Margin of the Image and for the allignement the HorizontalContentAlignement and VerticalContentAlignement :  <Image x:Name="imageNormal" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" HorizontalAlignement="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignement}" .../>

Comment: As for documentation this article about creating custom user control http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/creating-a-wp7-custom-control-in-7-steps and here is an article about attached property:http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Attached-Properties-in-Silverlight.aspx (it silverlight based but since wp is "based" on silverlight it apply exactly the same)